# hover over an html article and change the background of another div

Tags: jquery

I want to hover over an html article and change the background like so:

```
article:hover {background:#FFFFF0;}
```

and change article h3 to this:

```
article h3 {background:green}
```

I want to do this with a jquery function, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can try this in your CSS:

```
article:hover {background:#FFFFF0;}

article:hover h3 {background:green;}
```

If you are using SCSS, then this is easier to read:

```
article:hover {
  background: #FFFFF0;
  h3 {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle class on a hover event using jQuery.

```
$(function () {


    $('article').hover(function () {

        $('article h3').toggleClass('highlight');
    })

});
```

Style for the background color:

```
<style>
.highlight {
    background: green;
} </style>
```